# how to check if record stored in variable have count more than one

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my goal.

Check if count is more than 1 and if it is then, do task b and pass on the data to some other postgres function.

From web, I am able to understand that I can get count by something like this

```
select count(1) > 0 from public.perform_some_action(id)
```

but then I would be making a repetitive api call.

Instead I decided to get all the results and store it into `action_a`

```
select * from public.perform_some_action(id)
 WHERE user_id = driver_id_arg into action_a;
```

Here is the psudo code post that

- see if the count returned is greater than 1
- iterate over the results
- perform action b

Can someone help me in figuring out how I can do it?

Comment: in your pseudo code, you also will be making repetitive api calls.   You can put this type of logic in a script, or in a database procedure.  then you can call that procedure from a script, or from a trigger etc.  too many choices unfortunately to help without specifics.

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dceedda9e5233cba7706995ae8700675)

It is not quite clear to me, what you want to achieve. Here are three options:

First one: Use a subquery if you want to do different actions (here print out different texts) for cases `= 1` and `> 1`

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN cnt = 1 THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY id
) s
```

If you just want to handle the cases `> 1` and ignore the `= 1` cases, you can using the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    id,
    'b'
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Third idea is a bit different: If you need the data not to be grouped but need the original rows, you can use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) instead:

```
SELECT
    id,
    'b'
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as cnt
    FROM mytable
) s
WHERE cnt > 1
```